# Count the number of occurrences of keywords in an Array list

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String s = "nope";
    String v = "nopenopes";
    list.add(s);
    list.add(v);
    keywordCount(list, "nope"); 

}
public static int keywordCount(ArrayList<String> str , String keyword){
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0;i<str.size();i++){
    while ((i= str.indexOf(keyword,i)) != -1) { // here is where I found the error
          count++;
          i += keyword.length();    
}}

    System.out.println(count);
    return count;
}
```

hello, I'm writing a piece of code that counts the occurrences of a specific keyword inside an array list. It worked for a line of string but did not when trying to do the same thing for an arraylist. Can someone please point out what I did incorrectly and help me fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell use what result you expect and what the actual result is.

Comment: are you expect here output as 2? or you expect 1?

Comment: what error are you getting? Also there are many bugs in your code. 1. i<str.size() should be i<str.size()-1. 2. the variable i u are using for looping same variable you are assigning values too.

Comment: do you even expect 3?

Comment: That is a compiler error which means that `list` doesn't have a `indexof` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sue [Collections.frequncy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29)

```
 List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
 list.add("a");
 list.add("b");
 list.add("a");
 System.out.println(Collections.frequency(list,"a")); // out put is 2
```

Let's say you have a `List<String> list` then you want to find number of occurrence `keyword`

Then

```
int numOfOccurrences= Collections.frequency(list,keyword)
```

Answer (score 2):

Easily you can use `contains()` method;

```
public static int keywordCount(ArrayList<String> str , String keyword){
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<str.size();i++){
        if(str.get(i).contains(keyword)) 
          count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) to construct your `List`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(keywordCount(Arrays.asList("nope", "nopenopes"), "nope"));
}

public static int keywordCount(List<String> al, String keyword) {
  int count = 0;
  for (String str : al) {
    int i = 0;
    while ((i = str.indexOf(keyword, i)) != -1) {
      count++;
      i += keyword.length();
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

When I run the above I get the output

```
3
```

One issue in your code was

```
i = str.indexOf(keyword,i)
```

In your post `str` is not a `String`, it is an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

use code below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");
        list.add("a");

        // get all Unique keywords 
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
        for(String keyword: set){
            System.out.println(keyword + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, keyword));
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
b: 1
a: 2
```